# Cannot use UPDATE with OUTPUT clause when a trigger is on the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm performing an `UPDATE` with `OUTPUT` query:

```
UPDATE BatchReports
SET IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.BatchFileXml, inserted.ResponseFileXml, deleted.ProcessedDate
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid
```

This statement is well and fine; until a trigger is defined on the table. Then my `UPDATE` statement will get the error [334](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937592(v=sql.80).aspx):

> The target table 'BatchReports' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

Now this problem is explained in a blog post by the SQL Server team -- [UPDATE with OUTPUT clause – Triggers – and SQLMoreResults](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/update-with-output-clause-8211-triggers-8211-and-sqlmoreresults/ba-p/383457):

> The error message is self-explanatory

And they also give solutions:

> The application was changed to utilize the INTO clause

Except I cannot make head nor tail of the entirety of the blog post.

So let me ask my question: What should I change my `UPDATE` to so that it works?

### See also

- [UPDATE with OUTPUT clause – Triggers – and SQLMoreResults](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/07/11/update-with-output-clause-triggers-and-sqlmoreresults.aspx)
- [Why is the target table of a MERGE statement not allowed to have enabled rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504173/why-is-the-target-table-of-a-merge-statement-not-allowed-to-have-enabled-rules)
- [Statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537653/statement-contains-an-output-clause-without-into-clause-error)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Given the kludge needed to make `UPDATE` with `OUTPUT` work in SQL Server 2008 R2, I changed my query from:

```
UPDATE BatchReports  
SET IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.BatchFileXml, inserted.ResponseFileXml, deleted.ProcessedDate
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid
```

to:

```
SELECT BatchFileXml, ResponseFileXml, ProcessedDate FROM BatchReports
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid

UPDATE BatchReports
SET IsProcessed = 1
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid
```

Basically I stopped using `OUTPUT`. This isn't so bad as **Entity Framework itself** uses this very same hack!

Hopefully <strike>2012</strike> <strike>2014</strike> <strike>2016</strike> <strike>2018</strike> <strike>2019</strike> 2020 will have a better implementation.

---

### **Update: using OUTPUT is harmful**

The problem we started with was trying to use the `OUTPUT` clause to retrieve the *"after"* values in a table:

```
UPDATE BatchReports
SET IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.LastModifiedDate, inserted.RowVersion, inserted.BatchReportID
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid
```

That then hits the well-know limitation (*"won't-fix"* bug) in SQL Server:

> The target table 'BatchReports' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

### Workaround Attempt #1

So we try something where we will use an intermediate `TABLE` variable to hold the `OUTPUT` results:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
   LastModifiedDate datetime,
   RowVersion timestamp, 
   BatchReportID int
)
  
UPDATE BatchReports
SET IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.LastModifiedDate, inserted.RowVersion, inserted.BatchReportID
INTO @t
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Except that fails because you're not allowed to insert a `timestamp` into the table (even a temporary table variable).

### Workaround Attempt #2

We secretly know that a `timestamp` is actually a 64-bit (aka 8 byte) unsigned integer. We can change our temporary table definition to use `binary(8)` rather than `timestamp`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
   LastModifiedDate datetime,
   RowVersion binary(8), 
   BatchReportID int
)
  
UPDATE BatchReports
SET IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.LastModifiedDate, inserted.RowVersion, inserted.BatchReportID
INTO @t
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid

SELECT * FROM @t
```

And that works, ***except that the value are wrong***.

The timestamp `RowVersion` we return is not the value of the timestamp as it existed after the UPDATE completed:

- **returned timestamp**: `0x0000000001B71692`
- **actual timestamp**: `0x0000000001B71693`

That is because the values `OUTPUT` into our table are **not** the values as they were at the end of the UPDATE statement:

- UPDATE statement starting

  - modifies row

    - timestamp is updated *(e.g. 2 → 3)*
  - OUTPUT retrieves new timestamp *(i.e. 3)*
  - trigger runs

    - modifies row again

      - timestamp is updated *(e.g. 3 → 4)*
- UPDATE statement complete
- OUTPUT returns **3** *(the wrong value)*

This means:

- We do not get the timestamp as it exists at the end of the UPDATE statement (**4**)
- Instead we get the timestamp as it was in the indeterminate middle of the UPDATE statement (**3**)
- We do not get the correct timestamp

The same is true of **any** trigger that modifies *any* value in the row. The `OUTPUT` will not OUTPUT the value as of the end of the UPDATE.

*This means you cannot trust OUTPUT to return any correct values ever.*

This painful reality is documented in the BOL:

> Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect the data as it is after the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement has completed but before triggers are executed.

### How did Entity Framework solve it?

The .NET Entity Framework uses rowversion for Optimistic Concurrency. The EF depends on knowing the value of the `timestamp` as it exists after they issue an UPDATE.

Since you cannot use `OUTPUT` for any important data, Microsoft's Entity Framework uses the same workaround that I do:

### Workaround #3 - Final - Do not use OUTPUT clause

In order to retrieve the *after* values, Entity Framework issues:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[BatchReports]
SET [IsProcessed] = @0
WHERE (([BatchReportGUID] = @1) AND ([RowVersion] = @2))

SELECT [RowVersion], [LastModifiedDate]
FROM [dbo].[BatchReports]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [BatchReportGUID] = @1
```

Don't use `OUTPUT`.

Yes it suffers from a race condition, but that's the best SQL Server can do.

## What about INSERTs

Do what Entity Framework does:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @generated_keys table([CustomerID] int)

INSERT Customers (FirstName, LastName)
OUTPUT inserted.[CustomerID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES ('Steve', 'Brown')

SELECT t.[CustomerID], t.[CustomerGuid], t.[RowVersion], t.[CreatedDate]
FROM @generated_keys AS g
   INNER JOIN Customers AS t
   ON g.[CustomerGUID] = t.[CustomerGUID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

Again, they use a `SELECT` statement to read the row, rather than placing any trust in the OUTPUT clause.

**NOTE**: In 2022, Entity Framework added [a pre-mature optimization bug](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27372).

- in the same way you have to disable any use of `OUTPUT` in T-SQL
- you have to disable any use of `OUTPUT` by Entity Framework

Microsoft explains how to undo the bug added by [#27372](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27372):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().ToTable(tb => tb.UseSqlOutputClause(false));
```

With the down-side that you have to retroactively apply it to every table you have, or ever will have.

Comment: Ok everyone, how much does it SUCK that we have to resort to something like this?  I'm working on a 350 line stored proc, and for testing purposes I had intended to put in OUTPUT statements.  Of course I can't because of this bug.  Dumb oversight Microsoft.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and still gives the same error message

Comment: No better in 2016.

Comment: It's nice if you can switch your queries, but if you like me are mandated to use a 3d party DAL library which uses `OUTPUT` w/o `INTO` then you can only disable/re-enable or completely remove triggers.

Comment: You can fix the race condition in the last workaround by putting the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` in a transaction and a proper isolation level or a query hint in the `UPDATE`, at the cost of a slightly reduced concurrency.

Comment: What about `INSERT`, though? You wouldn't know the `id` of the row in order to `SELECT` it afterwards.

Comment: @Ryan Added to the answer the answer for `INSERT`. It's what Entity Framework does; they also gave up on using `OUTPUT` to output anything.

Comment: tldr: Your tldr is horribly wrong.  What if this `Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect the data as it is after the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement has completed but before triggers are executed.` is fine for my scenario (I need the value of an AutoNumber column.  The trigger is inserted related rows in other tables and has no effect on the primary target table, no even on its timestamp)?  In fact your recommendation for INSERT does still use `OUTPUT`

Comment: @BenVoigt *(In fact your recommendation for INSERT does still use `OUTPUT`)*. It does use `OUTPUT` - but not to OUTPUT anything i want to output That's because *(in general)*, you cannot use OUTPUT to output values you want to output. Yes, if i didn't have a trigger then i could risk it. But the lovely thing about this SQL Sever issue is that 7 years from now someone adds a trigger, and suddenly you'll get wrong values; in the worst case. In the best case the code will simply suddenly start crashing. So, in general, your answer is fragile and bad.

Comment: I don't get why the values from `OUTPUT` are wrong. The values I want to output are always the ones I put into my `INSERT`, I'm not interested in someone else's trigger modifying my results. `timestamp/rowversion` is no exception.

Comment: @Charlieface The problem is that the `rowversion` you get is not the `rowversion` in the database. This is especially disastrous for optimistic concurrency (e.g. the kind used by Entity Framework). But forgetting the disaster: it's just not-sensical - i asked for the value *"after"* my `CommandText` ran - it does not return that. You don't care about consistency and integrity: you're fine - you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: `for` / `after` triggers are meant to run after the update, so the SQL Server behavior with `ouptut` and such triggers modifying the data after the fact sounds expected to me, and not a bug.  
I have never tested them, but have you tried using an `instead of` trigger? It seems meant to fully replace the insert/update operation, allowing to change the data as you wish, allowing to actually do one single change statement on the data. It seems to me using such triggers should be the way to go when we want to change the modified data with a trigger.

Comment: @Frédéric I, like everyone else, expect `OUTPUT` to return the values as they after after the `UPDATE` statement has completed.

Comment: Is this going to b fixed in Entity Framework for SQL Server, or do we not upgrade to the newest version of EF?

Comment: @HrvojeBatrnek There is no bug in the Entity Framework. The Entity Framework is behaving exactly as it should.

Answer (score 57):

To work around this restriction you need to  `OUTPUT INTO ...` something. e.g. declare an intermediary table variable to be the target then `SELECT` from that.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
  BatchFileXml    XML,
  ResponseFileXml XML,
  ProcessedDate   DATE,
  RowVersion      BINARY(8) )

UPDATE BatchReports
SET    IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.BatchFileXml,
       inserted.ResponseFileXml,
       deleted.ProcessedDate,
       inserted.Timestamp
INTO @T
WHERE  BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid

SELECT *
FROM   @T
```

As cautioned in the other answer if your trigger writes back to the rows modified by the `UPDATE` statement itself in such a way that it affects the columns that you are `OUTPUT`-ing then you may not find the results useful but this is only a subset of triggers. The above technique works fine in other cases, such as triggers recording to other tables for audit purposes, or returning inserted identity values even if the original row is written back to in the trigger.

Comment: This workaround fails when your `@T` table contains a `timestamp` column - for example when you need to return the rows new timestamp for optimistic locking. SQL Server does not let you specify the values for a `timestamp` column, even if the column is in a temporary table variable.

Comment: @IanBoyd just include a column list that omits the time stamp column. `INTO @T (Foo, bar, Baz)` or if you are in fact trying to populate it declare it as `binary(8)` in the table variable instead of `timestamp`.

Comment: @IanBoyd - I've rolled back your edit. If you want to editorialize do it in some other venue. Such as your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why put all needed columns into table variable? We just need primary key and we can read all data after the UPDATE. There is no race when you use transaction:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE BatchReports SET 
    IsProcessed = 1
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @t(ID)
WHERE BatchReports.BatchReportGUID = @someGuid;

SELECT b.* 
FROM @t t JOIN BatchReports b ON t.ID = b.ID;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: This is certainly another valid alternative; that also completely negates the virtue of `OUTPUT` clause. You could also rewrite it as: `UPDATE BatchReports SET IsProcessed=1 WHERE BatchReportGUID = @someGuid; SELECT * FROM BatchReports WHERE BatchReportGUID = @someGuid;`

Comment: But you may not have the luxury of updating based on the primary key. The OUTPUT clause still provides goodness.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't have any OUTPUT statement in my query, but it raised the same error. Then I found this article from Microsoft released 27/03/2023:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers
It is a new behavior of EF. So, I have added the following code in my DB Context file in OnModelCreating() method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table_Name>()
           .ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("Table_Name_Trigger"));
```

It works find now.

Comment: thanks for the link, I ended up using the 'BlankTriggerAddingConvention' workaround instead :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are here just because you upgraded your application to EF7+ and you table has triggers associated with it and now you are facing this error.**

Go with 'BlankTriggerAddingConvention' method. Mentioned in [EF7 Breaking Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#sql-server-tables-with-triggers-or-certain-computed-columns-now-require-special-ef-core-configuration)

Thanks to #Pellet for mentioning in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Triggers are a code smell that can silently assassinate other parts of code.  Use stored procedures instead.  Instead Of triggers are even worse.  So, if you run into an Instead Of trigger, Output won't work even with an INTO, and neither will Scope_Identity.
For example:

```
CREATE   Trigger [DI].[TRG_AJC_BeforeInsert]
On [DI].[AJC]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
As
Set NoCount on
Insert Into [DI].[AJC] (val1, date2)
From Select [val1], getDate()
```

will return no results for Output or ScopeIdentity.  No results for Scope Identity because it hasn't been created yet, and no results for Output because it wasn't created at the time the OUTPUT was read.

Your only hope is that somehow the trigger didn't do another insert in another table.  Then you can use @@identity.  But if another table was updated/inserted during that session, you will now have @@identity returning that other table's identity, not the ScopedIdentity you were looking for.