# Output with trigger

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, triggers, insert

I have a table `Test` with columns

```
InveCode varchar(50)
itemid numeric(2)
rowid numeric identity,
purdate date
```

I have a trigger on this table.

```
Create trigger [dbo].[TrgInveCode] 
on [dbo].[test]
after insert
as
   declare @itemid numeric(10)
   declare @total numeric(10)
   declare @rowid numeric(18)
   declare @Date date

   select @itemid = i.itemid from inserted i
   select @rowid = i.rowid from inserted i
   select @Date = i.purdate from inserted i

   select @total = count(itemid) 
   from test 
   where itemid = @itemid and year(purdate) = year(@date)

   update test 
   set invecode= cast(@itemid as varchar(50)) + '-' + cast(year(@Date) as varchar(50)) + '-' + cast(@total as varchar(50)) 
   where rowid = @rowid
```

When I use this command

```
insert into test(itemid, purdate, buyingyear) 
output inserted.invecode 
values(@itemid, @purdate, @buyingyear)
```

in vb.net, I get this error:

> The targer table 'test' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Comment: Which dbms? (Most dbms products' triggers are not ANSI SQL...)

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-334.aspx    This might help..

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT i.RowId FROM Inserted i` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get an arbitrary row, and the other 24 will be **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: The error is pretty clear: if you have a trigger on the table, you **cannot** use the `OUTPUT` clause in that way. Either use `OUTPUT inserted.invecode INTO .........` or don't use `OUTPUT` at all

Comment: Please write complete code.  Marc_s

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `OUTPUT` clause on a table that has a trigger.

[Cannot use UPDATE with OUTPUT clause when a trigger is on the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table)

You have no choice but to `OUTPUT` the results `INTO` a table variable.