# target table `RECEIPT` of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `INVOICE` which stores bill information about an order/orders, one of the columns in this table is a column named `paid` which is a type of bit. As its name indicates, this column indicates whether the specific order/orders bill is paid or not.

I have another table named `RECEIPT`, this table stores information about any payment processes for a specific invoice.

So every time user pay an amount for the specified invoice, a new receipt record is created.

Now What I'm trying to do is to create a trigger that updates the `paid` column in the `INVOICE` table and set it to 1. This update process should be triggered in case of that the sum of receipts that belong to the invoice is equal to the `amount_due` in the `INVOICE` table.

In other words, if invoice due amount= 100$
and the user paid 50$
then, late he paid the other 50$
The `paid` column in the INVOICE table should be set to 1 as the total payments are equal to the invoice due amount

This is the trigger I've created to achieve the above

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_invoice_payment ON RECEIPT
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE INVOICE
SET paid = 1 
WHERE INVOICE.invoice_id = (SELECT inserted.invoice_id FROM inserted)
AND (SELECT SUM(RECEIPT.amount_paid) 
FROM RECEIPT 
JOIN inserted ON RECEIPT.receipt_id = inserted.receipt_id 
WHERE RECEIPT.invoice_id = inserted.invoice_id) = (SELECT INVOICE.amount_due 
FROM INVOICE 
JOIN inserted ON INVOICE.invoice_id = inserted.invoice_id 
WHERE INVOICE.invoice_id = inserted.invoice_id)
END;
```

it compiled successfully but at run time I've get the below error:

> The target table 'RECEIPT' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

Comment: The problem is in a piece of code you're not showing us, that is performing an `INSERT ... OUTPUT ...`, and, as the error message is also stating (quite clearly, IMO), it's not using `INTO`.

Comment: Also, your trigger is broken. `INVOICE.invoice_id = (SELECT inserted.invoice_id FROM inserted)` is going to produce an error when `inserted` contains multiple rows.

Comment: Is there auto incremented identity column for Receipt table?
Please refer:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-334.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think personally that you should update the `paid` status outside the scope of triggers. If you perform an `INSERT` into `RECEIPT`, you can execute the `UPDATE INVOICE ...` statement right after that (inside a `TRANSACTION` of course). A lot cleaner and predictable that way.

As to the error you are getting it's hard to say what is causing that based on the information you gave us. Perhaps the `TRIGGER` is triggering other `TRIGGER`s that produce the error you are getting? The statement you provided simply doesn't have an `OUTPUT` statement.

In any case, the statement you provided is not written correctly (as Damien pointed out) because the `inserted` table can have multipe rows. This is a rewrite to correct at least that part:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_invoice_payment ON RECEIPT
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        INVOICE
    SET 
        paid = 1
    FROM
        inserted AS ins
        INNER JOIN INVOICE AS inv ON
            inv.invoice_id=ins.invoice_id
    WHERE
        inv.amount_due=(
            SELECT 
                SUM(r.amount_paid) 
            FROM 
                RECEIPT AS r
            WHERE
                r.receipt_id=ins.invoice_id
        );
END;
```

But as I mentioned earlier you probably not be doing this from a `TRIGGER`. Execute this statement from your program right after any `INSERT/UPDATE`. Alternatively, write a Stored Procedure for inserting into `RECEIPT` and execute the `UPDATE` statement right after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm not that familiar with SQL syntaxes, but as I understand from the error, there must be an `INTO` clause if there was an `OUTPUT` statement, but actually my code and yours doesn't include any `OUTPUT` statement. I don't know if I'm understanding that properly, thanks again @TT

Comment: @AliAlhamaly There's no OUTPUT clause in this statement. That's your clue that you should be looking elsewhere for the cause of the problem you're having. GL!

Comment: I think I figured out the cause of the problem, the id column in the `RECEIPT` table is an auto-incremented identity column. Doing some search on google I found that an enabled trigger that includes an update statement cannot be triggered on a table that contains such id column, I mean an auto-incremented identity table. So I need now to workaround this problem to bypass this error. But still not sure if this is the actual cause

Comment: This [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table) seems to be about your case. You are inserting into/updating  receipt and the insert statement apparantly has an OUTPUT clause. Either you add an `INTO ...` to the statement, or rewrite your statement to not have an OUTPUT clause.