# SQL Server: Insert row with trigger after Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to insert another row into a table whenever a row is inserted using a trigger, but get the following error message:

> The target table 'EDDSDBO.Redaction' of the DML statement cannot have
>   any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause
>   without INTO clause.

Any help creating a work-around for this would be greatly appreciated.

From reading the links below my code is currently the following

[Cannot use UPDATE with OUTPUT clause when a trigger is on the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table)

[SQL Server Helper workaround](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-334.aspx)

Code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [EDDSDBO].[AddLabel]
ON [EDDSDBO].[Redaction]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T TABLE (
        [FileGuid] VARCHAR, [X] INT, [Y] INT, [Width] INT, [Height] INT
    )

    INSERT INTO [Redaction] [FileGuid],[X],[Y],[Width],[Height]
    OUTPUT [inserted].[FileGuid], [inserted].[X], [inserted].[Y],
           [inserted].[Width], [inserted].[Height]
    INTO @T
        SELECT
            [inserted].[FileGuid], [inserted].[X], [inserted].[Y], 70, 35
        FROM 
            inserted

    SELECT * 
    FROM @T
END
```

The `INSERT` code was originally the following before reading the links described:

```
INSERT INTO [Redaction] 
    [FileGuid],[X],[Y],[Width],[Height]
SELECT TOP 1 
    [FileGuid], [X], [Y], 70, 35
FROM [Redaction] AS r1
ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

**UPDATE:**
Turns out that kCura's Relativity platform does not allow inserting with triggers, so this was futile...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're inside a trigger, the trigger itself already defines the `Inserted` pseudo table for its use.

You *cannot* mix this with the `Inserted` alias that the `OUTPUT` clause would need.

Therefore, you **cannot** use the `OUTPUT`  clause in a statement inside a trigger.

Also: triggers should do their work *silently* and *not produce* any result sets!

**UPDATE:** the *proper* syntax for `INSERT` (which would be [**easily** found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)...) is:

```
INSERT INTO [Redaction] ([FileGuid], [X], [Y], [Width], [Height])
    SELECT TOP 1 
        [FileGuid], [X], [Y], 70, 35
    FROM 
        [Redaction] AS r1
    ORDER BY 
        [ID] DESC
```

You need to add *parenthesis* around the list of columns in the `INSERT INTO` line

Comment: Okay, but the code before using `OUTPUT` (which I've just added to the question) also threw the same error, why is that?