# Get OUTPUT table from SQL INSERT using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, output, sqldatareader

I am attempting to get the OUTPUT table from an INSERT command on a SQL Server database (v14).

```
 DECLARE @i TABLE (TICKET_ID int, CREATED_DATE datetime);

 INSERT INTO dbo.TICKET (SITE_ID, TICKET_TITLE, USER_ID) 
 OUTPUT INSERTED.TICKET_ID, INSERTED.CREATED_DATE INTO @i 
 VALUES (@s, @t, @q);

 SELECT * FROM @i;
```

I have 3 parameters that are being populated for the site, ticket title and user by @s, @t and @u respectively.

I am calling the command using a SqlClient.SqlDataReader Object with ExecuteReader Function on the 4.5 Framework.

The command successfully inserts the record into the database table, but does not return the table @i with the ticket ID (Auto Increment) and created date (default =GETDATE) which is what I am expected to present to the user once saved to the database.

I have played around with the removing of the @i TABLE in the command, but I get a .NET error:

> The target table 'name' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

I have found a couple of links that provide some ways to fix these but it did not fix my issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms971497(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

[Cannot use UPDATE with OUTPUT clause when a trigger is on the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198476/cannot-use-update-with-output-clause-when-a-trigger-is-on-the-table)

Is there any assistance that can be provided to assist in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you try your query in `SSMS` ? Does it work ? If it works, then check your `.NET` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a pain to have to but another option might be just to do this:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.TICKET (SITE_ID, TICKET_TITLE, USER_ID) 
 VALUES (@s, @t, @q);

 SELECT TICKET_ID, CREATED_DATE 
 FROM dbo.TICKET 
 WHERE SITE_ID = @s AND TICKET_TITLE = @t AND USER_ID = @q;
```

Comment: I removed the OUTPUT clause and used the @@identity reference to perform a SELECT to get the table data I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd need the table. I think you need to just execute this:

```
       INSERT INTO dbo.TICKET (SITE_ID, TICKET_TITLE, USER_ID) 
       OUTPUT inserted.TICKET_ID, inserted.CREATED_DATE
       VALUES (@s, @t, @q);
```

I can't see any value in the table. When you execute this statement, it'll return results to the client, just like a SELECT statement would.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I remove references to the @i temporary table, I get the following message: `The target table 'dbo.TICKET' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.`

Comment: Is there a trigger on the target table? What's it for? It'd be great if you don't need it. The inability to do it like that is a long term "bug" (at least in my mind) that I don't see being addressed any time soon.

Comment: So if you're stuck with the trigger, need to go back to your original query. Is there any chance it's coming back as multiple result sets? Have you tried doing a NextResultSet() call on the reader? (See if it's an extra result set)

Comment: Why do you need to use `OUTPUT`? Could you just do something like `select ticket_id, created_date from ticket where ticket_id = @@identity`?

Comment: There appears to be trigger on this table on the INSERT that I wasn't aware of.  So, I removed the OUTPUT clause from the command and then performed a SELECT using the @@identity.

Comment: Also, don't use @@IDENTITY. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead. SCOPE_IDENTITY() gives you the last identity value in your current scope. @@IDENTITY gives you the last identity value on your connection. So if there's an INSERT that you do, that triggers another INSERT (via a trigger), you'll get the  2nd IDENTITY value rather than the one that you want. SCOPE_IDENTITY() avoids that issue.